# Why my code not executing before syntax error causing line in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, typeerror

```js
// snippet for syntax error
console.log("hello stackoverflow!");
const test3;
test3='❌'
console.log(test3)

var name="me"
console.log(name)
```

I understand that JS is synchronous and execute code line by line,  but why over here `hello stackoverflow!` is not  getting printed, as the error is in the next line.

Also, Consider another snippet below

```js
// snippet for typeError
console.log('hello stackoverflow!')
const test3 = '✅'
test3='❌'
console.log(test3)

var name="me"
console.log(name)
```

This snippet prints the `hello stackoverflow`. Which is different behavior from the first snippet.

Can Anyone help me why it's happening and who identifies these errors in JS and does that happen before memory allocation in JavaScript?

I was expecting console.log() to get printed in both scenarios which is not happening in the first snippet.

Comment: You're setting a *constant* after the fact? That's a variable. Worth reading up on what [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) means. `const x` is not valid syntax. `const x = 'y'` is.

Comment: First scenario is a SyntaxError, they are detected before code execution. Second scenario is a TypeError, they happen at execution time. This is why you see 2 different behaviours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The order things happen in JS is [not strictly linear](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65425993/19068).

Syntax errors are scanned for before execution begins.

Comment: TypeError is also part of error, why then console.log code executed. 
As code execution should not begin if there error is scanned

Comment: Type Errors are not Syntax Errors. They are detected at a different time.

Comment: so JS do type checks ?

Comment: Probably not in the way you are thinking. This type error is because you are trying to reassign the value of a `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Interpreted language doesn't mean that it is executed line by line like a shell script. Many things happen before the first line is getting executed like variable space allocation.
If you define a variable in one way but use it another way the code execution won't start at all.
Please read about the code lifecycle: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/execution-context-how-javascript-works-behind-the-scenes/